# How to do a text mask on Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

So I have the table `CPF` and the column `cpf`.

| cpf |
| --- |
| 01234567890 |
| 12345678901 |
| 23456789012 |

I need the mask from cpf column like `000.000.00-00` (you can see `mask_cpf` column bellow that is what I want to do:

| cpf | mask_cpf |
| --- | --- |
| 01234567890 | 012.345.678-90 |
| 12345678901 | 123.456.789-01 |
| 23456789012 | 234.567.890-12 |

In the example below, from `to_char()` function I try to return a result like `'012.345.678-90'` (it's the string format for CPF here in Brazil).

I tried:

```sql
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(cpf, '000.000.000-00') AS cpf
FROM 
    CPF
```

```sql
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(cpf, '999.999.999-99') AS cpf
FROM 
    CPF
```

Both resulting on **error**: *multi decimal points*

After that, I tried according to documentation in redshift:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_formating.html

```sql
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(cpf, '999D999D999MI99') AS cpf
FROM 
    CPF
```

And the same error appears.

How can I do this mask? Thanks!

For more information about CPF: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadastro_de_Pessoas_F%C3%ADsicas

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `to_char()` function thinks that it is reformatting a number. This means that the period is being interpreted as a decimal, which doesn't work with your input number.

Instead, you could cheat like this:

```
select replace(to_char(01234567890::numeric, '000;000;000-00'), ';', '.')

012.345.678-90
```

Alternatively, you could create a [Create a scalar Python User-Defined Function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-udf.html) that does it with a less-complex call by putting the complexity into the function.

Comment: Thanks! It works but I'll continue looking for a smarter way. A function only to format this field it's can be a good idea.